# htaccess ruins CSS because of url structure. How to fix this?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My url after htaccessis

```
 devmode/verify/admin/1234
```

and the css on it are loading as

```
devmode/verify/admin/1234/css/theme-blues.css
```

the time that it should be

```
devmode/css/theme-blues.css
```

How to fix this?

Here is my full .htaccess file and the problem appears only on those 2 who have variables

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^verify/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ account/index.php?user=$1&verification_code=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^reset_password/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ account/index.php?password_reset&user_name=$1&verification_code=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login$ account/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^forgot_password$ account/index.php?password_reset [NC]
RewriteRule ^register$ account/index.php?register [NC]
RewriteRule ^logout$ account/index.php?logout [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Whitelist the css directory in your htaccess.

Comment: @anubhava at the very top just below `<head>` ?

Comment: Actually, never mind that, I thought your htaccess was rewriting the CSS url to index.php, but it's not... You just need to fix CSS paths in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either make all of your css links absolute URLs (they start with `/css/` or add the correct URI base to the header of your pages. That could be `<base href="/" />` or `<base href="/account/" />` based on what your rewrite rules seem to suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please tell me does the `<base...>` has something to do with performance issues?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos it's something that tells the browser that it needs to append that URL to the *front* of all relative URLs that it sees. The browser does this anyways using the URL in the location bar, all this does is tell the browser to use this URL instead.